# I'm trying to use the specific key ' in my binary converter program, but it creates a syntax error

Tags: java, string, binary, comparison, multidimensional-array

Here's a part of the working code. I give you a few examples of the working comparisons, but the comparison with the apostrophe (') key just doesn't work. Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
                else if(line.charAt(index) == ('%'))
                {
                    binaryList[rows][col] = "00100101";
                }

                else if(line.charAt(index) == ('&'))
                {
                    binaryList[rows][col] = "00100110";
                }

                else if(line.charAt(index).equals(''')) // this is the problem, its not working correctly like the others. 
                {
                    binaryList[rows][col] = 00100110;
                }

                else if(line.charAt(index) == ('('))
                {
                    binaryList[rows][col] = "00101000";
                }

                else if(line.charAt(index) == (')'))
                {
                    binaryList[rows][col] = "00101001";
                }
```

Comment: Note that you have not put `""` in the third `else-if`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should escape the `'` symbol. Like this:

```
line.charAt(index) == '\''
```

Answer (score 0):

You should escape the single quote with the backspace:

```
char x = '\'';
```